# Logstash 6.2.3 convert json values to GeoPoint Issue

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, geopoints

Hi I am new to ELK so first I want to setup custom json file read using logstash. I want to show the customer locations in kibana map . This is the json format I want to convert.

```
{"id":1,"first_name":"Freeman","last_name":"Jowers","email":"fjowers0@mashable.com","gender":"Male","ip_address":"15.128.77.162","latitude":9.9004655,"longitude":13.0544185,"date":"2017-10-29T17:47:59Z","country":"Nigeria"}
```

This is the Configuration file I have used for logstash.

```
    input {
  file{
    path => ["/home/sajith/Desktop/scripts/logstash-data/sample-data-006.json"]
    type => "json"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}
filter {
  grok {
    match => ['message','(?<body>\"id\":.*\"country\":\"[^"]+\")']
    add_field => ["json_body","{%{body}}"]
  }
  json {
    source => "json_body"
    remove_field => ["message","body","json_body"]
  }
  mutate{
    add_field => ["[geoip][location]","%{[latitude]}"]
    add_field => ["[geoip][location]","%{[longitude]}"]
  }
  mutate{
    convert => ["[geoip][location]","float"]
  }
}
output {
  stdout {
    codec => rubydebug
  }
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "my-mock"
  }
}
```

And the problem is in kibana geoip.location type shown as number . I need to show geoip.location as geo_point.
[image]

Can anyone give me the how to resolve this issue. I am using ELK 6.2.3

Answer (score 2):

There are a few issues. First, you need to set up the proper index mapping using the mapping below:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings" : {
    "_default_" : {
      "dynamic_templates" : [ {
        "message_field" : {
          "path_match" : "message",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text",
            "norms" : false
          }
        }
      }, {
        "string_fields" : {
          "match" : "*",
          "match_mapping_type" : "string",
          "mapping" : {
            "type" : "text", "norms" : false,
            "fields" : {
              "keyword" : { "type": "keyword", "ignore_above": 256 }
            }
          }
        }
      } ],
      "properties" : {
        "@timestamp": { "type": "date"},
        "@version": { "type": "keyword"},
        "geoip"  : {
          "dynamic": true,
          "properties" : {
            "ip": { "type": "ip" },
            "location" : { "type" : "geo_point" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Second, you need to create the `geoip` field properly like this:

```
  mutate{
    add_field => ["[geoip][ip]","%{[ip_address]}"]
    add_field => ["[geoip][location][latitude]","%{[latitude]}"]
    add_field => ["[geoip][location][longitude]","%{[longitude]}"]
  }
```

Finally, you need to remove the last `mutate/convert` filter.

Comment: Hi @Val I am not clear about index mapping. Can you please give me more about index mapping

Comment: You need to delete your index and recreate it with the command I gave above **before** indexing your first event.

Comment: Hi Val I will Try And let you know

Comment: Hi Val , When I try to update Index It gives this Error. Any Idea What is this {
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "cluster_block_exception",
                "reason": "blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"
            }
        ],
        "type": "cluster_block_exception",
        "reason": "blocked by: [FORBIDDEN/12/index read-only / allow delete (api)];"
    },
    "status": 403
}

Comment: Apparently, you're not allowed to delete the index. maybe create another one with another name

Comment: Hi Val Try removed All Indexes & Create New One And It also give the same Error.

Comment: Hi Val I have add the full configuration file If you have time to look in to this It will really helpfull